# Selenium-Webdriver returns StaleElementReferenceError on doubleClick action

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber-framework to do e2e testing and just recently, my double click method stopped working and have been returning StaleElementReferenceError ever since.

So my code goes as follows:

```
 generic.tableRows().each((element) => {
  element.all(by.tagName('td')).each((tdElement) => {
    tdElement.getText().then((rowCellText) => {
      if (rowCellText === identifier) {
        browser.actions().doubleClick(tdElement).perform();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The double clicking returns

> StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

But when I do:

```
tdElement.click();
```

The element is found and clicked. No errors are returned.

Things that I have tried:

```
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(tdElement), 10000).then(() => {
    browser.actions().doubleClick(tdElement).perform();
 });
```

--

```
browser.actions().mouseDown(tdElement).mouseUp().perform();
browser.sleep(1000); // Tried even without a hard wait
browser.actions().click(tdElement).perform();
```

--

```
tdElement.click().then(() => {
  browser.sleep(800); // Tried even without a hard wait
  tdElement.click();
});
```

-- And

```
browser.actions().click(tdElement).click(tdElement).perform();
```

Any help or insight to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At last you have tried clicking the same element twice. That did not work for you?

Comment: @BharathKumarS It didn't, unfortunately

Comment: Why would you force `doubleClick(tdElement)` when `tdElement.click()` works perfecto? What is your usecase? Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you for your response. Double clicking a td element in the table would redirect me to the specific page of the item double clicked. My html is just basically table that is filled with data by the restapi. I need a double click instead of a single click only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem!

The issue was that the outer 'each' function still persisted even after doing the double click action, which redirected the browser to another page, and the function was still looking for the elements which led to the StaleElementReferenceError because the element now doesn't exist on the page where the browser was redirected.

The solution was to simply use the ['filter'](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function instead of the 'each' function.

Answer (score 0):

A stale element error usually refers to a change in the dom taking place meaning the element has moved or something like that. Does it work if you perform a click and then find all the elements again and click again?

Comment: Yes I did. I have solved the problem though thanks for the response!